# SE API forgot how to order badges lexicographically

Tags: bug, status-review, badges, api

As of recently, the Stack Exchange API endpoint for listing named badges started to error out when choosing to sort the result set by name. Can this be fixed as soon as possible, please?

Switching to the `rank` sort option serves as a temporary workaround, but there are automation tools (like [ElectionBot](https://github.com/samliew/se-electionbot) that needs it to report voting stats during active elections [[first occurence of the issue](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61766908#61766908)]) dependent on the endpoint, and deoptimising requests just to work around the issue is something we would like to avoid.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to the API docs page for the [`/badges/names`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges-by-name) endpoint.
2. For the `sort` query parameter, choose `name`
3. Run the query and observe the `no_method` error:

[image: screenshot of the "no_method" error when requesting the API with the sort query parameter set to name for Chemistry SE]

Comment: The order is the problem. I can reproduce for any field when the order=desc. If I switch to order=asc things works

Comment: @rene oh, so it's worse than I thought... Then the number of affected tools is going to be much higher than I anticipated.

Comment: Yeah, something weird is borked

Comment: As far as I noticed, since yesterday, the API doesn't error out anymore and returned to full operation - is this [tag:status-completed] then?